# Commerce 1 create a new order programmatically

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, order

How can this be done in PHP?  I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

To add orders programmatically, you can do so by using the `Commerce_OrderModel` class.

Like so:

```
$order = new Commerce_OrderModel();
$order->email = 'test@example.com';

// Add your products here and other order info...
// .................

$success = craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($order);
```